# Do linux security modules (LSM) run on virtual server (vServer)?

Tags: security, virtual-machines, selinux

I have a vServer for 10 EUR/month from 1und1 and I know that it is not a dedicated machine (meaning I have less control). I know that I can use some the system as root, yet the kernel is untouchable. Therefore I wonder if a LSM can potentially be used?

Since I expect that the LSM is a kernel feature it seems to me that such a LSM is only possible to be used if the kernel I was provided with features it, right?

Maybe given this reasoning the question can be disected/broken down into:

part 1) is it always impossible to have a vServer do some LSM stuff?
part 2) or is it sometimes possible to have apparmor/sellinux etc on such a vServer?

maybe even 3) is there a way for me to check if a LSM is enabled in the kernel

feel free to add comments if the question is unclear.
If the question is false (i.e. if it cannot be clearly said if or if not that is possible please helpe me to specify the question!)

Last but not least, if the question seems out of place (i.e. if it should rather be in U&L SE) tell me!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question you should be asking your hosting provider. "Does the server you provide run/support `some feature`?" is always a question that should be asked of your provider's sales & support department.

Comment: @voretaq Sure there might be a point that the question can be "provider specific". Please consider that a virtualized server is different in a more general way from a dedicated server. This difference I think is of interest in a to SE-serverfault way. I think the question could help make clear if there is a way to have vServer have or not have LSM. I think it can be answered. Even if we might not be able to tell it. Or do you know if it or is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly 1&1 are using Parallels Bare Metal for their VPS products.

**1)**
Therefore (and referring to your post) you are regularly unable to run your VPS with a custom kernel or modify. So you are limited to the kernel and the modules/functionality provided by the host-node.

**2)**
Other Hypervisors (e.g. KVM / Xen) generally give you more control anbout the kernel and related functionality inside your VPS. As long as the hosting-company supports it you can have a full-featured OS with it's own kernel and modules as you like. This stock-kernel usually includes a LSM module like SELinux/AppArmor (depends on distro).

If you want you can go even further here and compile your own kernel enhanced with GRSecurity/PaX. But keep in mind it's VPS so is just as secure as the host system.

**3)**
SELinux: try *sestatus* or *getenforce*

AppArmor: try apparmor_status

(should be also possible to read this info from sysfs)

## EDIT

> in the 1und1 vServer I could none of sestatus getenforce nor
>   apparmor_status to work. I am curious what is meant by a Paralles Bare
>   Metal because if that is what I have then I have no access to use a
>   kernel whatsoever and no LSM. I do not know how to setup a safe
>   apache2 server like this. well thanks for your great answer!

Did you install the userspace tools (e.g. yum install policycoreutils on CentOS)? Those commands just work when the userland tools for the specific LSM are installed.

In your post you stated that you have no kontrol about the kernel. So I assume that you are unable to install the kernel supplied with your OS and also can't update / modify the kernel or even the bootloader.

In this case the best way is to get a 10 EUR KVM VPS from a good host (if possible one with security in mind). I could recommend one but I'm not a fan of covered advertising ;)

Safe apache in means of protection against the issue commonly called symlink race-condition?

Comment: in the 1und1 vServer I could none of `sestatus` `getenforce` nor `apparmor_status` to work. I am curious what is meant by a **Paralles Bare Metal** because if that is what I have then I have no access to use a kernel whatsoever and no LSM. I do not know how to setup a safe apache2 server like this. well thanks for your great answer!

Comment: Thanks so much for your update/edit. I have not yet seen this addition. I would appreciate to hear about a alternative provider for a KVM VPS . I understand that KVM is a option where I end up having more options regarding kernel and a more "real root server" options. ... I did install the userspace tool before checking. also the `/sys/kernel/security`.. in a nutsell I think the parallels VPS does not provide me with a LSM enabled kernel.